# Moving cell reference from another sheet by one without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've created a screenshot to explain what I'm searching for, it helps to understand my problem a lot better.

[image: Sheet A]

What you see is "Sheet A". In the yellow field there's is a reference to "Sheet B" (something like `='Sheet B'!E8`).
In the blue field I try to get the reference of the yellow field and add +4 to the row, so I'll get something like`='Sheet B'!I8`.
In the red field I try to get the reference of the yellow field and add +1 to the line, so I'll get something like `='Sheet B'!E9`.

The goal is to just copy and paste the data sets to the right and bottom, because I've got 44 data sets to the bottom and over 350 columns to the right. The yellow cell functions like a mother cell and every other cell is a reference to it.
I'd prefer a solution without VBA, so thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of OFFSET(), ROW() and COLUMN(). E.g. assuming the yellow cell is D4, you could put something like this into the yellow, red and blue cells:

```
=OFFSET('Sheet B'!$E$8, (ROW()-4)/6, 4*(COLUMN()-4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the offset function, this helps a lot.